# How to fetch the column names from Type(object)?

Tags: oracle, types

How to fetch the column names from Type(object)?Type means array of objects from Front end side.

Comment: I'm not sure that I follow the context.  We're presumably talking about a stored procedure that accepts a collection of objects.  If so, you'd have to know the object type at compile time which would mean that you'd know the fields of the object type.  Unless you're talking about something like a parameter of type `AnyData`?

Comment: @anand baskar,I replied answer,Does this make sense ..or you are asking something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not so clear but I assume you are looking for this:

```
SELECT *
FROM ALL_TYPE_ATTRS;
```

Comment: Thank you...i actually need is what u give:)

Comment: If this is the solution then please mark is at answered.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the syntax for creating a type to map rows from a table to it. Here i have a function which return type object array which is nothing but rows from table..

An object type can represent any real-world entity
You can define them as  below

```
create or replace type my_table_info as object(
COL1 VARCHAR2(40),
COL2 NUMBER,
COL3 NUMBER)
```

Accessing Object Attributes With Dot Notation

```
DECLARE
  info my_table_info;
BEGIN
  info := my_table_info('value1', 'value2', 'value3');
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(info.col1);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(info.col2);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(info.col3)  
END;
/
```

Below creates array of object

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE MY_TYPE as table of my_table_info
```

The function return the type array

```
create or replace function MY_FUNCTION(vi_col1     table.col1%type,
                                       vi_col2     table.col2%type,
                                       vi_col3     table.col3%type)
 return MY_TYPE as

 V_RESULTS MY_TYPE :=MY_TYPE();

 V_RESULTS.EXTEND;
 V_RESULTS(V_RESULTS.LAST):=MY_TYPE(vi_col1,vi_col2,vi_col3);

return V_RESULTS;
```

Now in your query, you can directly select column from type as below;

```
select col1,col2,col3 from my_table_info_function
```

Comment: I assume the question is how to get (according your example) `COL1`, `COL2`, `COL3`